# How to load development version of ES module with Webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, es6-modules

I'd like to be able to ship both development and production versions of an ES module and have the appropriate version loaded based on `NODE_ENV`. I want to provide warnings, notices and other developer experience niceties in dev builds but remove them in production builds.

Looking at React, a CommonJS module, you’ll see this pattern:

```js
 if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
   module.exports = require('./cjs/react.production.min.js');
 } else {
   module.exports = require('./cjs/react.development.js');
 }
```

This isn’t achievable with ESM since `import/export` statements must be at the top level of the script. Webpack has a concept of [mainFields](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolvemainfields) so you could specify something like `module:dev` and have that point to the dev ESM build but that’s not going work out of the box.

Is there a pattern for loading a development build of an ES module using Webpack?